# Combining portions of dictionaries for comparisons

Tags: python, dictionary, data-manipulation

I have an instance where I would like to compare data between dictionaries, nested in another dictionary.  The nested dictionaries all have the same format; it looks like this:

```
students = {"student_1": {"id":1009, "first_name": "Alex", "last_name": "Robertson",
                          "Assignments":[("Assignment_1",3),("Assignment_2", 4),
                                         ("Assignment_3", 2), ("Assignment_4", 4)]},
            "student_2" :{"id":2009, "first_name": "Dave", "last_name": "Davidson",
                          "Assignments":[("Assignment_1",2),("Assignment_2", 1),
                                         ("Assignment_3", 2), ("Assignment_4", 4)]},
            "student_3" :{"id":3009, "first_name": "Hayden", "last_name": "Miles",
                          "Assignments":[("Assignment_1",1),("Assignment_2", 1),
                                         ("Assignment_3", 1), ("Assignment_4", 1)]},
            "student_4" :{"id":4009, "first_name": "Randy", "last_name": "Bacon",
                          "Assignments":[("Assignment_1",2),("Assignment_2", 2),
                                         ("Assignment_3", 2), ("Assignment_4", 4)]},
            "student_5" :{"id":5009, "first_name": "Katrina", "last_name": "Lopez",
                          "Assignments":[("Assignment_1",2),("Assignment_2", 1),
                                         ("Assignment_3", 2), ("Assignment_4", 3)]},
            "student_6" :{"id":6009, "first_name": "Tessa", "last_name": "Franklin",
                          "Assignments":[("Assignment_1",1),("Assignment_2", 4),
                                         ("Assignment_3", 2), ("Assignment_4", 4)]}}
```

What I would like to do, is specify a specific assignment (the strings within the tuples) and pull out all six grades associated with that assignment and pair it with the ID number of the student.  For instance if I wanted the grades for Assignment_1, the result would be a list of tuples with the ID and the grade from the Assignment_1 or an ordered list of the student_#.  Any help is very much appreciated, this is what I have been trying to use:

```
def highest_n_grades(dict, tuple, int):
    save_data = []
    for d in dict:
     for k in d:
        if k == "Assignments":
            if [0] == tuple:
                data = d["id"],d["first_name"],d["last_name"],k[1]
                save_data.append(data)
    return save_data
```

The code runs, but only returns empty brackets.

Comment: Whats your expected input to this function, also whats your expected output

Comment: what do u mean by `if [0] == tuple`?

Comment: If the first element of "Assignments" is the same as tuple (which is a string that can be defined at the beginning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if-statement will always be False, since you are comparing a list with one value to a string.

You could try it like this (assuming "tuple" is a string):

```
search_assignment = "Assignment_1"

def highest_n_grades(students, search_assignment):
    save_data = []
    for student in students:
        student_data = students[student]
        assignments = student_data["Assignments"]
        for assignment in assignments:
            if assignment[0] is search_assignment:
                data = (student_data["id"], student_data["first_name"], student_data["last_name"], assignment[1])
                save_data.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit towards my understanding. This code extracts the grades of students for a given assignment.

```
def highest_n_grades(dict, tuple):
save_data = []
for d_id,d_info in dict.items():
    assignments = d_info['Assignments']
    for el in assignments:
        if el[0] == tuple:
            data = d_info["id"],d_info["first_name"],d_info["last_name"],el[1]
            save_data.append(data)
return save_data
```

Use case :

```
highest_n_grades(students,'Assignment_1')

 [(1009, 'Alex', 'Robertson', 3),
 (2009, 'Dave', 'Davidson', 2),
 (3009, 'Hayden', 'Miles', 1),
 (4009, 'Randy', 'Bacon', 2),
 (5009, 'Katrina', 'Lopez', 2),
 (6009, 'Tessa', 'Franklin', 1)]
```